# Matching a time pattern in django urls

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I want to match the following url

```
/calendar/entry/add/2013/11/23/05:30
```

my urls.py

```
 url(r'^entry/add/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<day>\d+)/(?P<time>\d+:\d+)/$', 'view')
```

and on main urls.py I have

```
url(r'^calendar/',include('mycal.urls'),
```

but it isnt working...and I get a no match. What is the right regexpr for this....

Answer (score 1):

The url `/calendar/entry/add/2013/11/23/05:30` does not contain trailing `/`.

Remove the trailing `/` from the url pattern or make it optional  to make it match with the url

```
url(r'^entry/add/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)/(?P<day>\d+)/(?P<time>\d+:\d+)/?$', 'view')
#                                                                           ^^
```

Comment: nope....Still the same message...no match...I am thinking it's the regular expression that is the error here....

Comment: @Apostolos, Could you post the error message (preferably with traceback) by editing your question?

Comment: After 8 hours i can hardly see what i type...I had the url wrong from the template(via javascript)....so i was matching the wrong url with the right reg exp....Thank you. Please delete the question as I don't think it will really help anyone...

Comment: The answer or the question?Can i delete it?